# Method invocation ... may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В `activity_main.xml` отображаю `view` :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

В методе `onCreate` внутри `Activity`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
EditText textEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textEditText);
textEditText.method();
```

Но при вызове любого метода у `textEditText` `Android Studio` предупреждает, что

> Method invocation ... may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Разве такой исход возможен? Или это ошибка?

Comment: почему вы думаете, что какой-либо метод не может в определенных обстоятельствах вернуть null, так же думаю нужно указать какой именно метод вызывает это предупреждение.

Comment: @pavlofff в методе onCreate при любом методе. Например при каком обстоятельстве textEditText  будет равен null?

Comment: Просто в последние версии AS добавили инспекций, связанных с null-безопасным кодом, это сейчас стало очень модным (null-безопасный код), вот она и выдает по любому поводу, просто игнорируйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев становится ясным, что в данном примере NPE произойти не может и можно смело игнорировать это предупреждение.

Answer (score 1):

Это предупреждение означает, что на момент вызова `textEditText.method();` в переменной `textEditText` может находиться `null`. Например, вследствии того, что `findViewById` перед этим не смог найти в вашем леяуте `View` для указанного `id`. В таком случае в `textEditText` запишется `null`

Comment: Студия по идее должна увидеть строку setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) и что внутри xml есть EditText с таким id и null не может быть возвращен

Comment: Но если textEditText.method() вызвать в другом методе, предупреждения нет

Comment: @iamtihonov студия не настолько умная, и просто рекомендует вам во избежание NPE проверить, а точно ли нашолся этот `View`

Comment: @Да наверное так и есть, я просто думал может действительно есть ситуации, когда вернет null, даже если все правильно прописал

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы действительно получить `null` вместо `EditText` из вашей разметки, нужно заставить запуститься метод `onCreate` без отображения активити на экране. Например так:

1. Создаём в классе активити дефолтный конструктор.
2. В нём вызываем `onCreate`
3. В `onCreate` создаём экземпляр класса активити.
4. Вуаля - при создании экземпляра вызовется `onCreate` и приложение упадёт.

Упасть оно, конечно, может уже и на `setContentView`. Я не проверял, конечно же, свою идею.
Ещё оно, вроде, так ещё и в рекурсию может уйти, если, вдруг, не упадёт)

Думаю студия как раз таки учитывает возможность вызова к-л метода из конструктора и просто не знает, что конструктор у активити переопределять и использовать не надо и ваш код в нормальных условиях падать не должен.

Comment: Попробовал так сделать, падает на super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), выдает NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.parentActivityName' on a null object reference

Comment: @iamtihonov, ой, а пробовать-то и не надо - это ж я специально очень неправильный способ использования активити пытался придумать коий точно должен где-то упасть))) И это всё к тому, что да, IDE не всегда бывает права и надо просто учитывать, что все нюансы ей объяснить её разработчики никогда не смогут. Т.е. в вашем конкретном случае её предупреждение лучше проигнорировать.

Comment: Т.е. для актвити и фрагментов создание конструктора это почти наверняка получение к-л ошибки, ибо система сама должна конструкторами оперировать и вмешиваться в этот процесс не следует.